# ID generator class for my Repair Shop Software

Tags: java, beginner, generator

I have made a ID generator class for my **[Repair Shop Software](https://github.com/EmperorZoran/Repair-Shop-Software)**, that generates new ID for all data entities that are used in the software. It also converts `int` value of the ID to `String` value used for UI, and `String` values used for UI, to `int` value. I would like a general opinion on my `IDGenerator` class. Am I using some anti-pattern, and is my code clear enough. My project is on the [GitHub](https://github.com/EmperorZoran/Repair-Shop-Software).

**IDGenerator.java**

```
public class IDGenerator
{
    private static final int WORKSTATION_ID = 1;
    private static final int DAY_ID_FORMATER = 100;
    private static final int MONTH_ID_FORMATER = 10000; 
    private static final int YEAR_ID_FORMATER = 1000000;
    private static final int WORKSTATION_ID_FORMATER = 100000000;
    private static final int WORKSTATION_ID_VALUE = WORKSTATION_ID * WORKSTATION_ID_FORMATER;

    private static LocalDate lastTicketDate = LocalDate.MIN;

    public static int getNewID(EntityType entityType)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(entityType, "EntityType is null");

        int entityCounter = DataManager.getEntityCounter(entityType);

        switch(entityType)
        {
            case TICKET:
            {
                checkNewWorkDay();

                LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

                int dayIDValue = today.getDayOfMonth() * DAY_ID_FORMATER;
                int monthIDValue = today.getMonthValue() * MONTH_ID_FORMATER;
                int yearIDValue = (today.getYear() % DAY_ID_FORMATER) * YEAR_ID_FORMATER;

                return entityCounter + 1
                     + dayIDValue
                     + monthIDValue
                     + yearIDValue
                     + WORKSTATION_ID_VALUE;
            }
            default:
            {
                return entityCounter + 1 + WORKSTATION_ID_VALUE;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void checkNewWorkDay()
    {
        if(lastTicketDate != LocalDate.now())
        {
            DataManager.resetTicketCounter();
            lastTicketDate = LocalDate.now();
        }
    }

    public static String toString(EntityType entityType, int id)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(entityType, "EntityType is null");

        String workstationID = String.valueOf(id / WORKSTATION_ID_FORMATER);

        switch(entityType)
        {
            case TICKET:
            {
                String date = String.valueOf((id % WORKSTATION_ID_FORMATER) / DAY_ID_FORMATER);
                String dailyTicketCounter = String.valueOf(id %  DAY_ID_FORMATER);

                if(dailyTicketCounter.length() == 1)
                {
                    dailyTicketCounter = '0' + dailyTicketCounter;
                }

                return workstationID + "-" + date + "-" + dailyTicketCounter;
            }

            default:
            {
                String entityCounter = String.valueOf(id % WORKSTATION_ID_FORMATER);

                return workstationID + "-" + entityCounter;
            }   
        }
    }

    public static int toInt(EntityType entityType, String displayName)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(entityType, "EntityType is null");

        if(LabelName.NULL_ITEM.equals(displayName))
            return 0;

        int workstationID = Integer.parseInt(displayName.split("-")[0]) * WORKSTATION_ID_FORMATER;

        switch(entityType)
        {
            case TICKET:
            {
                int date = Integer.parseInt(displayName.split("-")[1]) * DAY_ID_FORMATER;
                int entityCounterNumber = Integer.parseInt(displayName.split("-")[2]);
                return workstationID + date + entityCounterNumber;
            }
            default:
            {
                int entityCounterNumber = Integer.parseInt(displayName.split("-")[1]);

                return workstationID + entityCounterNumber;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**IDGenertatorTest.java**

```
public class IDGeneratorTest
{
    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(EntityType.class)
    public void getNewIDTest(EntityType entityType)
    {
        switch(entityType)
        {
            case TICKET:
                assertEquals(119123001, IDGenerator.getNewID(entityType));
                break;

            default:
                assertEquals(100000001, IDGenerator.getNewID(entityType));
                break;
        }
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(EntityType.class)
    public void toStringTest(EntityType entityType)
    {
        switch(entityType)
        {
            case TICKET:
                assertEquals("1-191230-01", IDGenerator.toString(entityType, 119123001));
                break;

            default:
                assertEquals("1-21", IDGenerator.toString(entityType, 100000021));
                break;
        }
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(EntityType.class)
    public void toIntTest(EntityType entityType)
    {
        switch(entityType)
        {
            case TICKET:
                assertEquals(119123001, IDGenerator.toInt(entityType, "1-191230-01"));
                break;

            default:
                assertEquals(100000021, IDGenerator.toInt(entityType, "1-21"));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we should describe a [user-story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story) for your ID-generator. This description should contain use-cases (including examples), requirements, and related technical context.

#### Use-Story

As *creator of a **new entity*** (system) I would like to make sure that this entity can be identified within the system by an **[Identifier (ID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifier)**. So the ID should be **automatically generated** when the new entity is created and persisted.

As **administrator or user** of the system I would like to **read some information** about the entity directly from the generated ID. So
the ID should be a [Natural Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) which encodes some business information.

**Requirements:**

1. the ID should be **numerical**
2. depending on the **entity-type** the ID could vary in shape/pattern
3. the **pattern** and information encoded into the ID should **tell something** about it. Thus it contains *informational parts*, each encoded as a number. Parts may be *workstation-id*, *running-counter* or *creation-date*
4. the *informational parts* (numbers) of the ID are **separated by** a dash `-`
5. the **running-counter** should be (at least) **unique per entity-type**
6. the **default ID** (if not specified separately for the entity-types) should contain two parts: (a) *workstation-id* as 1-digit, (b) *running counter* as 2-digits. So the pattern `<workstation_id>-<count>` can for example be represented as `1-01` for the first **entity XY** (*running counter* `01`) created on *workstation* `1`.
7. the ID of an entity-type **TICKET** should consist of one extra information: (c) *creation-date* as 6-digit ISO-date in format `yyMMdd`. So the pattern `<workstation_id>-<date_yyMMdd>-<count>` can for example be represented as `1-191230-01` for the first **ticket** (*running counter* `01`) created on *workstation* `1` on `30th of December 2019`.
8. additionally the **running-counter** of entity-type **TICKET** should be **reset on each new creation-date**. So that the *running-counter*
   is unique within each creation-date.

#### Design & Modelling

Now you can **model the data structures** needed to fulfill the requirements, i.e. classes or interfaces.

**class `EntityID`**:
learn from Java's [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class and its implemented interfaces:

```java
public class EntityID implements Serializable, Comparable<EntityID> {
  public static final String SEPARATOR = "-";
  public static final int REQUIRED_PARTS = 2;

  protected int workstationId;
  protected int counter;

  public EntityID(int workstationId, int counter) {
    // could add some parameter validation (like only positive values)
    this.workstationId = workstationId;
    this.counter = counter;
  }

  @Override // implements Comparable<EntityID> 
  public int compareTo(EntityID value) {
    // needed to make sure if compared objects are same, or for sorting: lesser, greater
    // left for you to implement
    return -1;
  }

  public static EntityID fromString(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArumentException("ID to parse must not be null or empty!");
    }
    String[] parts = name.split(SEPARATOR);
    if (parts.length != REQUIRED_PARTS) {
      throw new IllegalArumentException(String.format("ID to parse must consist of %d parts, separated by '%s', but was: %s", REQUIRED_PARTS, SEPARATOR, name));
    }
    int workstationId = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int counter = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    return new EntityID(workstationId, counter);
  }

  // getter and setter for all information parts
  // left to implement

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%01d%s%02d", workstationId, SEPARATOR, counter); 
  }
}
```

This class servers the **default ID**. For the special case **TICKET** you need to inherit this class, as follows.

**class `TicketId`**:

```java
public class TicketID extends EntityID implements Serializable, Comparable<TicketID> {
  public static final String SEPARATOR = "-";
  public static final int REQUIRED_PARTS = 3;
  public static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMdd");

  protected LocalDate creationDateUtc;

  public TicketID(int workstationId, int counter, LocalDate utcDate) {
    super(workstationId, counter);
    this.creationDateUtc = utcDate;
  }

  @Override // implements Comparable<TicketID> 
  public int compareTo(TicketID value) {
    // needed to make sure if compared objects are same, or for sorting: lesser, greater
    // left for you to implement
    return -1;
  }

  public static TicketID fromString(String name) {
    if (name == null || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
      throw IllegalArumentException("ID to parse must not be null or empty!");
    }
    String[] parts = name.split(SEPARATOR);
    if (parts.length != REQUIRED_PARTS) {
      throw new IllegalArumentException(String.format("ID to parse must consist of %d parts, separated by '%s', but was: %s", REQUIRED_PARTS, SEPARATOR, name));
    }
    int workstationId = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    LocalDate utcDate = LocalDate.parse(parts[1], DATE_FORMATTER);
    int counter = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    return new TicketID(workstationId, counter, utcDate);
  }

  // getter and setter for all information parts
  // left to implement

  public String toString() {
    // could also use a DateFormatter like
    // return String.format("%01d-%s-%02d", workstationId, DATE_FORMATTER.format(creationDateUtc), counter);
    return String.format("%01d-%tY%tm%td-%02d", workstationId, creationDateUtc, counter);
  }
}
```

**Note:**

How **parsing** (form *representation* String to *value* ID) and **formatting** (from *value* ID to *representation* String) was implemented using static facotry method `fromString` and instance method `toString`.

The above classes implement requirements 1. - 4. and 6. - 7.

Now the ID-generator comes into play. Using [Factory](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) *Design-Pattern* we can implement it like follows.

The `counter` for each entity-type should be managed inside the generator, not be dependent on some DataManager. Thus make use of Java's **concurrent** counter classes [AtomicInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818699/practical-uses-for-atomicinteger]

```java
public class EntityIdGenerator {

   protected AtomicInteger counter;
   protected Integer counterMax;
   protected Integer workstationId; 

   // here the current value from DataManager can be injected as counterStart
   // counterMax = 99 (limit to 2-digits), workstationId = 1
   public EntityIdGenerator(int counterStart, int counterMax, int workstationId) {
     if (counterMax <= counterStart || counterStart < 0 || counterMax < 1) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("CounterStart must positive and >= 0, counterMax must be > 1 and > counterStart"!); 
     }
     this.counter = new AtomicInteger(counterStart);
     this counterMax = counterMax;
     this.workstationId = workstationId;
   }

   protected int rollToNextCounter() {
     // if current counter is 99 == counterMax, then reset  
     boolean hasReachedMaxAndReset = this.counter.compareAndSet(counterMax, 0);
     // if counterStart was 0, the nextCounter will also be 0 (first used) 
     return this.counter.getAndIncrement();     
   }

   public EntityID generateId() {
     return new EntityID(this.workstationId, rollToNextCounter());
   }

}
```

The above class has some benefits:

- can now be **tested isolated** without need of some DataManager (independent)
- can now have different instances (each of it manages state for a special entity-type, and its counter).

With the last (multiple instances) we implemented requirement 5.

- can be *specialized*, meaning it can be inherited to some class `TicketIdGenerator` which manages some property `lastIssuedDateUtc` in order to reset the counter even if the `counterMax` has not yet reached.

```java
public class TicketIdGenerator extends EntityIdGenerator {
   private LocalDate lastIssuedDateUtc;

   public TicketIdGenerator(int counterStart, int counterMax, LocalDate lastIssuedDateUtc) {
     super(counterStart, counterMax);
     if (lastIssuedDateUtc > todayUtc()) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("date (as UTC) must can be now or in the past; must not be in the future: " + lastIssuedDateUtc);
     }
     this.lastIssuedDateUtc = lastIssuedDateUtc;
   }

   public LocalDate todayUtc() {
     return LocalDate.now("UTC");
   }

   public TicketID generateId() {
     if (this.lastIssuedDateUtc < todayUtc()) {
       this.lastIssuedDateUtc = todayUtc();
     }
     return new TicketID(this.workstationId, rollToNextCounter(), this.lastIssuedDateUtc);
   }

   // rest of logic and methods remain same as in EntityIdGenerator

}
```

With above we implemented requirement 8.

Comment: This is not a code review. You are suggesting your own solution without considering  the code in question. You also come up with your own requirements disregarding requirements that can be deriven from question/code in question

Comment: Above code is not yet tested plus there are at least 2 points not yet designed: (a) `TicketID` represented by non-UTC date (in local timezone); (b) assignment of each ID-generator instance to respective `EntityType`. If you see some mistakes (e.g. one method should be static), comment ;-)

Comment: @purple Yes it's my proposal of an improved design (not one monolithic class, violating SRP, etc.).  I will explain and provide _traditional_ review-comments to OP's source tomorrow. And please __list the requirements__ that _you can derive_ from OP's post !?

Comment: I appreciate your extensive answer, and I intend to implement some of your suggestions. **Test isolation** is one of my concerns, and I was thinking of re-implementing `IDGenerator` just because of that.

Answer (score 3):

Using static methods only for your `IDGenerator` class is antipattern. It's better to make those instance methods and create instance of your class when you need it. One reason may be extendability, another can be thread safety. I have a feeling, that static local variable `lastTicketDate` will probably cause trouble with race conditions.

If you really want to have static access to it, consider making it singleton with static method to get the instance. It's not ideal, but still better approach and it's on the way to making your code non-static, keeping reference to your class in local/class variable rather than static access. Thread safety can still be issue since any thread can access statically your class as long as there is static method to get it.

Comment: You may have some misconceptions about singletons. You don't have static access to a singleton since a singleton is an object (that guarantees that there is only one instance). Singletons are also usually an anti pattern. You should rely on dependency injection in order to guarantee against duplicate instantiations. Static access has nothing to do with guaranteeing thread safety. Same restrictions apply as with instance methods.

Comment: True it was a bit vague (edited a bit). I meant access to singleton using static factory. I never said that singleton is best way, I suggested it as mid-way to better code that doesn't require full refactor. I also never said that static access guarantees thread safety, quite opposite - I mentioned, that it can still cause issue. If you wanna talk this through or chat or something, I am happy to discuss.

Comment: Can you explain me what bad could potentially happen in the program with my solution regarding thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain addition is going to create identical ID's.  For instance, if for 1 ID the `dayIDValue` is 6 and the `monthIDValue` is 5, you'll get the same ID if next time the `dayIDValue` is 5 and the `monthIDValue` is 6.

I would suggest using the [`UUID` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).  It allows you to choose different versions depending on how unique you need the ID's to be.

Comment: Yes, I have consider using UUID numbers for ID's, but they are very large considering I plan to have entire database in RAM. I don't think you have read the code of my class, because the possible duplicate ID is only possible if the daily ticket counter is larger then 99, but that would be prohibited in the client. If you see the test class it will be clear. The **fifth** ticket on the workstation with the workstation ID of **2** on **31.12.2019.** will have **219123105 ID**. My ID also caries some information unlike UUID. Thank you for your suggestion.